# Does this video prove that a provably dead person in Michigan voted by absentee ballot?

Tags: united-states, politics

In [this video on Twitter](https://twitter.com/chrisbergpov/status/1324407060281188352), the presenter use the Michigan Voter Information Center webpage, to show that a man born in 1902 applied for and sent in a mail in ballot in the 2020 US election. It is claimed that this is evidence of dead people voting, i.e. voter fraud.

It seems pretty damning, at least in the case of one individual vote.  But is it true?

Comment: Can you summarize what’s happening in the video in the question body?

Answer (score 25):

**The Michigan Secretary of State has claimed these allegations are false, and has provided explanations.  The votes were real, and were cast, but the dates of birth on these votes are wrong due to similar names to living relatives of the deceased.**

---

From [Local 4 News in Detriot](https://www.clickondetroit.com/news/2020/11/05/did-a-dead-118-year-old-man-vote-absentee-in-michigan-state-says-no/)

> “Ballots of voters who have died are rejected in Michigan, even if the voter cast an absentee ballot and then died before Election Day. On rare occasions, a ballot received for a living voter may be recorded in a way that makes it appear as if the voter is dead.

> This can be because of voters with similar names, where the ballot is accidentally recorded as voted by John Smith Sr when it was actually voted by John Smith Jr; or because of inaccurately recorded birth dates in the qualified voter file; for example, someone born in 1990 accidentally recorded as born in 1890. In such scenarios, no one ineligible has actually voted, and there is no impact on the outcome of the election. Local clerks can correct the issue when it is brought to their attention.”

[Logically.ai](https://www.logically.ai/factchecks/library/0dd425c5) has found the supposed "deceased" voters.

> All three people who voted are alive and most likely relatives of people born in the early 1900s and inherited their relatives' names.

> A Twitter user called Essential Fleccas claims that three people who are already dead voted for Joe Biden in Michigan. According to the video published by the handle, June Aiken (120 years old), Donna Brydges (119 years old) and William Bradley (118 years old) voted for Biden via absentee ballots. Rudolph W. Giuliani, the president’s personal lawyer, also claimed that dead people voted in Michigan. This false information is used as evidence of voter fraud.

> We found that all three people are alive and most likely are relatives of the people born in the early 1900s and inherited relatives' names. William Tarnley Bradley lives in Michigan, and he is 61 years old. His ZIP code is the same as the ZIP code of his passed relative, William Bradley, born in 1902. Donna Bridges lives in Michigan, Ludington, and is 75 years old and June Aiken lives in Michigan and is 94 years old.